# Could a vaccine injecting B cells theoretically work?

Tags: immunology, pharmacology, vaccination

So I was in the car riding to school today when I was struck with genius. Each B cell is attuned to a different pathogen, am I correct? By that logic, would a vaccine injecting a dose of B cells attuned to the pathogen you're trying to protect against work?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, take the cells out, purify, multiply them with the right stimulus and reinject.

You have been struck with genius, but I think some other people with the same idea got prizes already. Good to see you thinking, dont stop!

A review of just one application of this is here.

"Cancer Immunotherapy"

by

Wennhold K.a · Shimabukuro-Vornhagen A.b · von Bergwelt-Baildon M.

https://www.karger.com/Article/Fulltext/496166

permanent ref is http://doi.org/10.1159/000496166